# Error enabling custom https on CDN custom domain

Tags: azure, https, azure-cdn

When enabling Custom HTTPS on our Custom Domain on our Azure CDN, I get the following error:

> (BadRequest) We found a CAA record for your custom domain that does not include DigiCert as an authorized Certificate Authority so we cannot have DigiCert generate a certificate for you. Either consider adding "issue" "digicert.com" to your CAA records or remove all CAA records from your domains DNS zone.

This occurs via the CLI (`az cdn custom-domain enable-https`) and through the web portal.

We have digicert set up as an appropriate CAA record through Cloudflare:

```
dig +short CAA mydomain.ca | sort
0 iodef "mailto:caa@mydomain.ca"
0 issue "comodoca.com"
0 issue "digicert.com; cansignhttpexchanges=yes"
0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
0 issuewild "comodoca.com"
0 issuewild "digicert.com; cansignhttpexchanges=yes"
0 issuewild "letsencrypt.org"
```

Could the existence of `; cansignhttpexchanges=yes` be the cause of the issues? This worked fine in our development environment a few weeks ago, and is on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

As this WAS working for app services, we ended up opening a ticket with MS and they resolved the issue on their side. We are now able to provision as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for Azure CDN Verizon and Microsoft SKU, the CAA record value are strictly limited to below values: https://docs.digicert.com/manage-certificates/dns-caa-resource-record-check/#valid-caa-resource-record-values

- digicert.com
- [www.digicert.com](http://www.digicert.com)
- digicert.ne.jp
- cybertrust.ne.jp
- symantec.com
- thawte.com
- geotrust.com
- rapidssl.com

Please trim the "; cansignhttpexchanges=yes" and have a retry.